# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sslwrap'

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, ssl, boto

I am trying to make a ssl connection to aws from using boto in python(2.7.8).Internally it is using gevent function.I am getting error like this-

```
` File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/sts/connection.py", line 384, in assume_role

    return self.get_object("AssumeRole", params, AssumedRole, verb="POST")

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1192, in get_object

    response = self.make_request(action, params, path, verb)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1116, in make_request

    return self._mexe(http_request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 943, in _mexe
    request.body, request.headers)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 995, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1029, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 991, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 844, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 806, in send
    self.connect()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/https_connection.py", line 131, in connect
    ca_certs=self.ca_certs)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/ssl.py", line 383, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/ssl.py", line 85, in __init__
    self._sslobj = _ssl.sslwrap(self._sock, server_side,

  AttributeError: "module" object has no attribute "sslwrap"
```

I am using amazon linux machine(AWS)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You possibly did a `import some_module as _ssl`?

Comment: save yourself, use boto3.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this could be related to https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/477

Upgrading gevent from `1.0.1` to `1.1.1` resolved the issue for me:

```
$ pip install --upgrade gevent
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using pip from Python 2.7.12 (the one currently in the official Ubuntu 14.04 ppa).

Updating to Python 2.7.13 (https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/) solved the issue for me.